# Neo 2.3.2 performance issues

Tags: neo4j

Just upgraded from 2.2.5 to 2.3.2 and a previous query that executed immediately now takes a considerable time. Seems linked to the depth as reducing it form 5 to 3 makes it quicker.

More details are as below,
Following is the Neo4j query used to search the recommended restaurants for the passed user_id, where depth/degree of the search is kept as 5.

```
MATCH (u:User {user_id:"bf9203fba4484f96b4983152e9ee859a"})-[r*1..5]-(place:Place)
WHERE ALL (rel in r WHERE rel.rating >= 0)
RETURN DISTINCT place.place_id, place.title, length(r) as LoR ORDER BY LoR, place.title
```

Old server instance has Neo4j 2.2.5, where result is displayed instantly but on new VM with Neo4j 2.3.2 it is taking quite long time to return the result.
If we decrease the search depth value to 2 or 3, queries are running faster

Anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: What about to delete and recreate indexes?

Comment: is the old server also a VM?

Comment: do you have a dedicated rel-type for your relationship? and a direction?

Comment: are you actually looking for the longest path?

Comment: and could you share the query plan from a PROFILE run?

Answer (score 0):

How do the query times compare when running completely non-warmed-up, e.g. just start server and run this query? I'm suspecting property loading may be the biggest problem due to the removal of the object cache in the 2.3 series.

Do the `Place` nodes and relationships w/ the `rating` property have many properties each?